# Using bluetooth command without root access in 17.04

Tags: permissions, xubuntu, bluetooth, xfce

Back in 16.04 I could use the `bluetooth` command in my Xfce session startup and it turn bluetooth off at least until the applet turns it on when the panel loads, which I worked around with a simple script, but not the command now requires root privileges, how can I make it not require that?

```sh
#!/bin/sh
bluetooth off
blueman-applet & # This application is disabled in session startup
while [ "$(bluetooth | cut -d' ' -f3)" = "off" ]; do
    sleep 1
done
bluetooth off
```